# How do I actually play the SC2: Legacy of the Void Beta?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've purchased and claimed the Legacy of the Void Beta, such that my account details show it against my account:

[image: Battle.Net: Game Accounts]

Clicking on that icon takes me to this page with information about the Beta, however there's nothing to indicate a 'Download the Beta now' or instructions on how to play:

[image: Battle.Net: LotV Beta screen]

The Battle.Net app also doesn't have any indication of how to launch the 'Beta' mode, so I assumed it was accessible after launching Starcraft:

[image: Battle.Net application screen]

And yet there's nothing after launching the game that screams "Access the Beta content by clicking here right now!" either (unfortunately screenshots of the game menu seem to fail so I can't show this).

Of course, my Google-fu is failing me: everything I find simply tells me **to** pre-purchase the game, or **how** to pre-purchase the game, without any indication of how to actually launch and play it.

So, How do I actually launch and play the Beta and/or the Prequel missions?

Comment: This is a guess based on the WoW/D3 PTR (since I'm not in the LotV beta), but try the dropdown that says Region/Account on the Battle.Net client.

Comment: @Troyen - Omg, which brilliant spark at Blizzard thought THAT was a good idea?!? Yeah that's it. Would you care to add it as an answer?

Comment: There used to be a link on the website for betas, not sure why they got rid of it.  It's definitely not very noticeable now.

Comment: @Troyen - yeah that's what I remember from the previous SC2 Beta as well. SC2 is the only game I play on Battle.Net so I don't visit the site that often or participate in any other games/betas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the Account/Region dropdown menu on the Starcraft page in the Battle.Net client.  Similar to how you would install the PTR for other games.

[image: How to install the Legacy of the Void beta.]

Picture sourced from