# How do I play the prologue missions from prepurchasing Starcraft 2: Legacy of the Void?

Tags: starcraft-2

I just prepurchased Legacy of the Void so I can play the exclusive prologue missions (I have no interest in multiplayer). However, I cannot find them anywhere in my campaign list in Starcraft 2. I've seen people play them on Youtube, but I can't find them.

Do I need to install the beta to play them? Do I need to wait for my account to get flagged properly? Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Unfortunately I think I ran into the same problem as you :/. Did you pre-purchase a digital copy or activate a code from a store? If the latter, I don't think we get access to the prologue missions. Otherwise, they should be available in the beta under 'Campaign'

Comment: @Robotnik I bought a digital copy. I rarely buy games in a store these days, not when Belgian internet is this good. So I need to install the beta to play them eh? If you can put that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you purchased the game digitally, they will be available through the Starcraft 2: Legacy of the Void Beta Client. You will need to install the Beta and launch it to access the missions.

Click on the 'Campaign' button, and on the Whispers of Oblivion page, click the 'New Campaign' button to begin playing the Prologue.

[image: Whispers of Oblivion Launch Page]

You can [access the Beta from the Battle.Net Client](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/237127/28182). Change the Region dropdown to *'Beta: Legacy of the Void'* and click install.